# C++ equivalent to SerializeWithLengthPrefix

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I built a communication library using Protocol Buffers (protobuf-net) using Sockets (TcpListener and TcpClient) and it is working fine, but now a co-worker needs to write a library to communicate with my software using C++.

Turns out that I'm using the `Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix` and `Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix`.

Are there equivalent functions in the protobuf C++ libraries? If not, anyone knows how to implement it, or have it implemented to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not *hugely* familiar with the C++ API; but the length prefix itself is pretty simple if you write the data to a buffer first, especially if you use the fixed-width 32-bit encoding (rather than base-128 variable-length). See also [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf/browse_thread/thread/32550c50fa795837/6d5df18467c75869) on the google-groups forum.

Comment: Unfortunately, the referenced thread does not include any information on interoperating with a C# (de)serialized end from C/C++ when the C# side uses PrefixStyle.Base128. Since you mention that the resultant message is also a valid protobuf message, could you provide an example for the two cases? Thanks!