# Raw proto representation of protobuf-net (De)SerializeWithLengthPrefix

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

First of all, this is NOT a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468589/c-equivalent-to-serializewithlengthprefix) other question so please read my question fully before flagging it.

I need to write out raw proto files that match up with C# (de)serialized messages read and written using Serializer.NonGeneric.(De)Serialize. I currently use PrefixStyle.Base128 and would like to continue doing so (unless using PrefixStyle.Fixed32 is the only way forward).

For example, given a message:

```
message KeyValuePair {
   optional string Key = 1;
   optional string Value = 2 [default = ""];
}
```

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/MlUMUPp5WDc) Google groups thread, @marc-gravell says "*...SerializeWithLengthPrefix method, by default, aims to represent data in a way that is a valid protobuf stream - in particular, as though it were simply a member of a parent object or list...*"

What would the "*parent object or list*" look like in a raw proto definition when serialized using

```
Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(<stream>, new KeyValuePair { Name = "foo", Value = "Bar" }, PrefixStyle.Base128, <unique_message_id>)
```

?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message DummyDoesNotExist {
    optional KeyValuePair Value = <unique_message_id>;
}
```

On the wire, this is then:

```
varint: [wire-type: length-prefixed, field: <unique_message_id>] // typically 1 byte
varint: [length] // typically 1 or 2 bytes
[length bytes of KeyValuePair data]
```

Comment: Perfect. That's *exactly* what I needed. Thanks!